# Unable to obtain configuration from: '/.well-known/openid-configuration' when trying to validate JWT

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure-active-directory, authorization

The application in question is set up like this: there is a frontend service, and a backend service. The backend service is registered in Azure AD. The frontend service uses the clientId and tenantId of the registered app to receive a JWT via the Auth Code flow. The frontend then passes this JWT in the authorization header of each request.

The next step is getting the backend service to validate this token to give access to its endpoints. There are a ton of different examples out there and I'm finding it hard to determine what to use. Currently I have this in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
```

With appsettings.json:

```
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "https://myapi.azurewebsites.net",
    "TenantId": "xxxxx-xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxx",
    "IssuerId": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx",
    "ClientId": "xxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx"
  }
```

When I try using postman to call an endpoint with a JWT in the header I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Resource temporarily unavailable
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (11): Resource temporarily unavailable
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.GetAsync(String address, IDocumentRetriever retriever, CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

I have no idea what this means or how to fix it. Some sites suggest to specify the metadataAdress, but they don't tell you what to specify or where to put it. Does anyone have any experience with this error?

Answer (score 2):

According to my test, if you want to protect your web api with Azure AD, please refer to the following steps

1. [Register  Web api application in Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app)
2. [Configure your api scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-expose-web-apis)
   [image]
3. [Register client application in Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis)

   a. Register application

   b. Create client secret
     [image]

   c. Configure API permisiions
     [image]
4. Configure application

   a. appsettings.json

   ```
   "AzureAd": {
   "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
   "TenantId": "<your azure ad tenant id>",
   "Domain": "<your azure ad domain>",
   "ClientId": "<you web api appid>"

   },
   ```

   b. Add the following code in `startup.cs`.

   - ConfigureServices method

     ```
      public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
     {
        var tenatId = Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"];
        services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.JwtBearerAuthenticationScheme)
      .AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
        services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(AzureADDefaults.JwtBearerAuthenticationScheme, options =>
        {
            // This is a Microsoft identity platform web API.
            options.Authority += "/v2.0";
            options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuers = new[] {

              $"https://sts.windows.net/{tenatId}/",
              $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenatId}/v2.0"

            };

            // The web API accepts as audiences both the Client ID (options.Audience) and api://{ClientID}.
            options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidAudiences = new[]
            {
                 options.Audience,
                 $"api://{options.Audience}"
            };

        });
     ...
     }
     ```
   - Configure method

     ```
      ...
     app.UseRouting();
     app.UseAuthentication();
     app.UseAuthorization();
      ...
     ```
5. Test

[image]
[image]

Comment: Which nuget package are you using ? (Im using .NET 4.8, not core). Thanks.